# Can I fix heat regulator (burner switch) of electric range?

Tags: switch, oven, range

So the burners stay on no matter what setting - low or high. I opened and found the switches (heat regulator) were the problem.

The metal contact of the green board is broken because it's too thin.

[image]

Thus, no connection between #1 and #2 (picture below). The electric range could not turn off the burner when it reached the desired temperature.

A. The metal contact at #1 is sharp. I wonder if I can bend the tip to make better contact.

B. At #2, I'm thinking about putting some solder there.

Will these fixes cause potential problems?

I don't want to buy a new switch because it will definitely fail in the same manner. (I don't know why engineer designed it this way. If this is the case, I blame sale management)

[image]

Comment: that little green card is the heater that warms the bi-metallic strip it probably gets fairly hot.  you may be able to repair it with solder or it may get too hot for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, what you're suggesting will probably work. I have similar repairs on "ON & OFF" switches..BUT... The contact at #1 looks like a limiting device to break the circuit in an overheat situation. I wouldn't be messing with that. The problem as I see it is the burners wouldn't turn off. So if your fix doesn't work, the problem will return when you lest expect it..... Is it worth it?  How old it the range?  I'd be, and have done many times, buying a new switch. Many times the internal designs of these switches are improved and you'd never know it by the outside appearance so the existing problem you have might never occur again. My advice is to think twice about messing with range/oven switches. Good luck.

Comment: It's a samsung glass top. The range is about 4 year old. The first switch stopped working about a year ago, the second switch about 6 months ago. An OEM switch is about $60, ebay aftermarket is $35. I've done some searching around and a lot of people have the problem.

Comment: I didn't solder #2, just smooth it, bend #1 then put the cover back. It's working for now.  Do you know when turning the burner on, you have to push the knob in, mine doesn't do that. So #1 and #2 make contact all the time before I did the fix.